# uri mapping - '/index.php/dashboard'

Tags: nginx

In Apache, I can access php scripts through an uri like `/index.php/dashboard`,
how can I set nginx to act the same?

Also I can access `/index` with Apache and it automatically maps to `/index.php`.
Is this also possible in nginx?

I think something like this is the solution:

```
map $uri $myvalue {
    /index.php/(.*)    /index.php?$;
}
```

Or is there a solution w/o rewrite?

Update, current config:

```
server {
        listen   80;
        charset utf-8;
        root /www/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        access_log  /www/log/access.log;
        error_page 404 /www/public/http-404.php;
        server_name rasp;

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                allow ::1;
                deny all;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        location / {
                autoindex on;
                try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php /;
        }


        location /dev/ {
                auth_basic "dev";
                auth_basic_user_file /www/config/global.passwd;
                location ~ \.php$ {
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                }
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Comment: What does your current config look like?

Comment: @MichaelHampton put it into the question

Comment: That should be sufficient. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton on accessing `/index.php/test` or `/index` I get _No input file specified._ in both cases

Comment: I set the PHP variable to `cgi.fix_pathinfo=0` as suggested in the Debian default config, could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there are any security issues with this its what i use in my testing enviorment

```
if (!-e $request_filename)
{
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
    break;
}

location ~ \.php    {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/index.php;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /path/to;
    }
```